# Is it efficient to query on a sub-index

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I want to query on a table which has an index for columns a,b,c,d all together. 
If in the where clause I filter on columns a, b and c, is the index good enough? Or should I create a new index just for the tree fields (a, b and c) ?

```
alter table myTable add index (a,b,c,d)
```

...

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE a = ? AND b = ? AND c = ?
```

Comment: It's perfect for a,b,c, but useless for b,c,d

Comment: @Strawberry, Please care to explain this a bit also.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai The manual covers this in great detail

Comment: index usage is left used, meaning the `index (a,b,c,d)` can handle `WHERE a = ?`, `WHERE a = ? AND b = ?`, `WHERE a = ? AND b = ? AND c = ?`, `WHERE a = ? AND b = ? AND c = ? AND d = ?` effective..   A trick can be using `WHERE a >= 'a' AND b = ?` or  `WHERE a >= 1 AND b = ?` for example when you don't know the a value to search for **but it will cause a full index scan then which is less efficient** but most likely faster then a full table scan as index files are generally (much) smaller vs table files.

Comment: An index on `(a, b, c, d)` is obviously larger than one on `(a, b, c)`. That can make the difference of how much of the index fits into memory and how much of that data in memory needs to be replaced with other parts of the index from disk during execution. Disk operations are expensive, so using a smaller index, possibly minimizing reads from disk, can have its benefits.

Comment: indeed @stickybit MySQL's InnoDB engines (secondary) indexes are stored clusterd aswell.. So if the `PRIMARY KEY` information will also be stored within the `index (a,b,c,d)`

Comment: The order matters; the `=` vs `>=` matters; the `*` matters (if that is a,b,c,d in any order then the index is "covering", which is beneficial); etc.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has good [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on multi-column indexes.  You should read it.

To understand how such indexes work, basically there are two operations on a standard index:

- The index can be be used to look up specific values.
- The index can be scanned between two values (or until a second value is reached).

(MySQL does not support a third method, skip-scans.)

An index on four columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, is optimal for conditions on these four columns where the columns have equality conditions -- in order -- and at most one non-`=` condition at the end.  For example:

- `a = ? and b = ? and c = ?`
- `a = ? and b < 10`
- `a = ? and b = ? and c = ? and d in (?, ?, ?)`
- `a between ? and ?`

The index can be used partially, particularly when `a` has an equality condition and other columns are mentioned:

- `a = ? and d < ?`
- `a = ? and c in (?, ?, ?) and d < ?`

However, the index is being scanned in this situation, with non-matching rows being discarded.

I cannot think of any circumstances where it is useful to have two indexes, where one is strictly prefixes of the other -- such as `(a, b, c, d)` and `(a, b, c)`.  It can be useful if the indexes are not strict prefixes, such as `(b, c, d)` or `(a, c, b, d)`.